# Using Codable to decode JSON which doesn't have the same structure you would like

Tags: ios, swift, macos, codable

I have used `Codable` before successfully to decode JSON when the JSON in question matches up to the model I am wanting to use in my app.

The JSON I am talking about is https://www.reddit.com/r/earthporn/hot.json.
Here I am only interested in the object at `data.children[i].data.preview.images[0].source` so basically In my app all I care about is an array of this model

```
struct Wallpaper: Codable {
    let url: URL
    let width: Int
    let height: Int
}
```

I don't want to create the whole schema as huge nested structs just so that I can decode the one part at `data.children[i].data.preview.images[0].source`

Is there any way to do this using `Codable` or would this be better suited to using

`let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]`

and then traversing down the whole tree to create my objects? Or is there another solution which I have not considered?

Thanks

Comment: “Or is there another solution which I have not considered?” Yes, implement `init(from:)` and traverse the nested containers.

Comment: So id create the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` method on `Wallpaper` and traverse each nested container right down to the data I want correct?

Comment: Yes, see the linked answer. You’ve got a mixture of keyed and unkeyed containers to pass through but the idea is exactly the same. On the other hand creating a nest of structs with just the one property you need to take you down to the next level is even easier and faster to write. No law requires your struct to express the _whole_ json at that level, you know. You could have written the thing in the time it took us to have this conversation!

Comment: Yep, I was aware I could've have created nested structs but just wanted to know of any alternate ways to do this. Thanks for the response anyhow.

Comment: @matt the linked answer is spot on for what I wanted. Cheers

Comment: No worries, glad if it's right.